# How can I save lists to file as obtained from parallel computation in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

My (Python 3) code looks something like this:

```py
from itertools import product
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
comb = product(x, x)
pool = Pool()
results = pool.starmap(my_function, comb)
```

where `my_function` returns several lists (basically a list of lists) for each `comb` item. Since the amount of lists returned end up consuming all my RAM, I'd like to save the lists to a file as they are produced.

I know that if I just write `pool.starmap(my_function, comb)` without assigning it to `results`, the lists are print to the screen. How can I instead save to file?

Should I rewrite `my_function` to append to a file and pass the filename as the third element of each tuple in `comb`? Wouldn't that slow down my code a lot by opening the file so many times?

Comment: Write to a the file in `my_function` would be the most straight-forward way.

Comment: Everything to same file?

Comment: Yes, I'd like everything saved to the same file. One list per line as white-space separated values is optimal.

Comment: Can you provide a sample output of my_function, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q** : *How can I instead save to file?*

One may define one's own file-I/O handling as per requirements, or one may re-use an already working framework, like the smart one from **`logging`** module.

> **Q** : *Wouldn't that slow down my code a lot by opening the file so many times?*

The `logging` module can dispatch all the `logging`-originated messages into the system's syslog-service, or into a `Queue`-instance ( for process-based backends in `multiprocessing` or `joblib` originated concurrent-processing schemes, that do not share python objects while being intentionally separated into autonomous processes ) so avoiding all the "manual" file-I/O operations and letting the services work for you.

More details on consolidation of messages from distributed-computing and [multiple processes](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes)